# Upload File into Document Set

Tags: document-set

I've got a Problem with an upload CustomAction I built. It should open upload.aspx and allow me to upload a file to a document set in a document library. I don't know how to build Rootfolder-parameter correctly, because it behaves different from common folders.
My CommandUIHandler looks like this:
`<CommandUIHandler Command="xxxUploadDoc_Ribbon_Command"
                          CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('{SiteUrl}/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={ListId}&amp;RootFolder={ListUrlDir}&amp;Source={Source}&amp;IsDlg=1');"
                          EnabledScript="javascript:CheckIfIsDocSetPageUpload() == 1;" />`
I'm using SP2010std.

Comment: missing what it looks like! Also, what version of SP?

Comment: Oops, I corrected it:)